# Not getting expected answer on OrderAgnostic Binary Search.Leetcode problem no "34. Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array"

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search

Actually this is a leetcode problem no **34. Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array.**In this I code solution in java in vscode.but I can't able to get expected answer.

*MY Code:-*

```
class OrdAgsBS{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] ans={-1,-1};
        int[] nums={1,2,3,4,5,3,1};
        int target=3;
     ans[0]=search(nums,target,true);
    ans[1]=search(nums,target,false);

        for(int ch:ans)
         System.out.print(ch+" ");

    }
       public static int search(int[] nums,int target,boolean startInd){
             int start=0,end=nums.length-1,ans=-1;
         while(start<=end){
          int mid=start+(end-start)/2;
             if(target<nums[mid])
              end=mid-1;
             else if(target>nums[mid])
              start=mid+1;
             else{
                 ans=mid;
                 if(startInd)
                       end=mid-1;
                 else
                   start=mid+1;
         } 
       }
       return ans;
      }
}
```

In this above code I builded logic correctly according to my intutive approach.But I expect answer for this will be

[2,5].The first index of 3 and last index value of 3.But If i compile above code I get answer [2,2].I don't know what is the problem.Can anyone help me to rectify it.

Comment: When you find the number, you should stop the binary search. You should then somehow traverse the list to the left and right of the found index to find the first and last occurrences of the found variable because you don't know if the binary search has found the first, last, or any other occurrence of the number.